# Can't turn airplane mode off - it requires a hardware switch that my lenovo

Tags: wifi-hardware-switch, airplane-mode

Can't turn airplane mode off - it requires a hardware switch that my lenovo laptop x130e does not have.
Ubuntu 18.04
    `rfkill list all`
tells me that
both the WiFi and Bluetooth
 are
hardware blocked
 but not
software blocked
Thanks for any help

Comment: Has it ever worked? Go into the BIOS settings and reset them to factory defaults. Then check and make sure that WiFi has been enabled.

Comment: Check Lenovo support at https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x130e/solutions/HT500407 - it may be `F5` or `Fn+F5`

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answers. The F keys didn't work. The other solutions explained in the link didn't work so I tried the BIOS factory default reset. Viola! It now works. Thanks. I have no idea what attribute change fixed it. But now I am a happy camper. Now I have not be able to find a way to mark this thread as ANSWERED.